# Find points with slope parallel to function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find all points (a, b) on the curve y = x^3 - x + 1 where the tangent line is parallel to the line y = 11x + 5.

Just need confirmation on how to complete this problem. You take the slope of the second function and set it equal to the derivative of the first function?

Comment: You got it right.